What is the Keras 3 version of this numpy function of this IEEE754 to Unsigned Integer 8 normalization?
Using the Keras 3 ops api, what is the Keras 3 version of this normalization function?
def ieee754_to_uint8(x, axis=-1):
  """
  Normalize a tensor using IEEE 754 logic and map it to uint8 values.

  Args:
      x (tensor): A Keras tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_len).
      axis (int): Axis along which to normalize.

  Returns:
      A Keras tensor with dtype uint8, returning the same shape as input x.
  """
  # Find the maximum absolute value in x
  m = np.max(np.abs(x), axis=axis, keepdims=True)
  m[m==0] = 1

  y = (2**7 - 1 * (x > 0)) * x / m
  return (y.astype(int) + 128).astype(np.uint8)

